# Header Help for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

noobie to Magento, took days for me to figure out the structure block and content block thing but I think I understand it.  I created a block to hold an image but it puts a space between my logo and search bar, I'd like them to be on even ground.  What I was thinking of doing is finding the .phtml file that outputs the logo and search bar....but I'd have no idea what I'd do then and I have no idea where that is.  I know where the column .phtml files are and the Header, head etc. but not specifically the place I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Magento :)

To quickly answer your question, the header is built in `app/design/frontend/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/template/page/html/header.phtml`

But Magento also has a preaty neat feature where it shows the template and it's corresponding block for each frontend piece that is loaded. To activate it, open your store admin, switch to the store view level (top left dropdown called `Current Configuration Scope`) and go to `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug` and set both `Template Path Hints` and `Add Block Names to Hints` to yes.

Next clear your cache, load the frontend and enjoy :)